# SQL SELECT WHERE without underscore and more

Tags: sql, string

I want to select where 2 strings but without taking
underscore
apostrophe
dash..

Hello !
I want to select an option in my SQL database who look like this :

```
Chef d'équipe aménagement-finitions
```

With an original tag who look like this

```
chef-déquipe-aménagement-finitions
```

Some results in database had a - too

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(name, '-', ' ') = REPLACE('chef-déquipe-aménagement-finitions', '-', ' ')
```

didnt work because of missing '
And a double replace didn't work too.
I want the string be able to compare without taking
underscore
apostrophe
dash
and all things like that
is this possible ?

Thanks for your help
Have good day !

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column collation?

Comment: This sounds like a task that should be done in whatever application is using the database, not the database itself. Strip the `-` before you insert and before checking for an entry. It will speed up the query by quite a bit too.

Comment: Why should double replacement not working?

Comment: you need to replace the single quote by nothing first, then space by dash. That should give you what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your rdbms, but here's how I would perform in MySQL 8. If using a different version or rdbms, then first determine how to escape the single quote and modify as needed.

```
with my_data as (
  select 'Chef d''équipe aménagement-finitions' as name
  )
select name, 
  lower(replace(replace(name, '\'', ''), ' ', '-')) as name2
from my_data;
```

| name | name2 |
| --- | --- |
| Chef d'équipe aménagement-finitions | chef-déquipe-aménagement-finitions |

---

Sql-server and Postgres version:

```
lower(replace(replace(name, '''', ''), ' ', '-')) as name
```

After posting, this, I re-read and noticed you are also looking to replace other characters. You could either keep layering the replace function, or, look into other functions.